# How to declare webdriver objects in Java globally common to all methods

Tags: java, global-variables

I am creating few test scripts in Selenium Web-Driver using Java.
I have Test-case classes and Page classes. The Page classes have methods which are not declared as 'Static'.
So I am creating objects for the Page classes in my test cases and passing the driver to them.
The test case class gets the driver from the base class.

Would like to know on the below.

1. How I can declare the objects common to two methods in the Test case class so that I can use one object common across two methods inside the test case class.

My sample code

Test Case Class

```
    public class Classname extends basepage()

    /
    **I would like to declare the 'log' object globally here**
    /

    public void method1()throws exception
    {
       Login log=new Login(driver);
    }

    public void method2() throws exception
    {
      Login log=new Login(driver);
    }
```

2. Is it a good practice to declare objects in Test case classes. Or is it mandatory to declare them as 'Static' methods in the Page Classes?

Kindly let me know.

Thanks,
Mohan.

Comment: you can declare at class level, and yes if you are using it in main method, it must be static

Comment: There's no such thing as a global variable in Java. Isn't what you're talking about just [a field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html)?

Comment: Thanks. I meant declaration at Class level so that the object is common to both the methods. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, the object can be declared at the class level. However, I think the best practice is to instantiate the variable in your setUp method (or constructor).